# Clicking on a link a sending request to another site without refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is the situation - I have a Raspberry Pi 2 (it's connected to the TV) and I'm running Kodi on it to play movies. I want to build my own movie database, so i could browse all the movies on the extarnal hard drive that is connected to the raspberry. I have found out that I can play a movie with kodi by sending a request to the server from a nother computer on the network. For example if I enter the following URL in the web browser on my machine:

```
http://192.168.0.102:8080/jsonrpc?request={"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"1","method":"Player.Open","params":{"item":{"file":"/media/serverhdd/cloud/Movies/Ex Machina/Ex Machina.mkv"}}}
```

The movie Ex Machina (kodi has to be running) will start. I have the following code:

```
<a class = "play_movie" href = "http://192.168.0.102:8080/jsonrpc?request={"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"1","method":"Player.Open","params":{"item":{"file":"/media/serverhdd/cloud/Movies/Ex Machina/Ex Machina.mkv"}}}">Pleay movie</a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.play_movie').click(function(){
                var movie_url = $(this).attr('href');
                $.ajax({
                    url: movie_url,
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert('done');
                    }
                });
            }); 
        </script>
```

When I click on the link, kodi starts playing the movie, but I'm going to this URL and getting this message:

{"id":"1","jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"OK"}

What I want is to stay on the current page instead of going to the URL above. I've checked here and on other places and it seems that I should be able to do that with AJAX, however with the code above, I'm going to the URL, instead of staying on the current page.

Could you please advise how can I do this?

This would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,
Ivan

Comment: then have your `.click()` function return false to prevent the click from doing what it normally would...

Comment: It's not working - now I'm staying on the current page, but the movie is not starting...

Comment: well,  you are just assuming that the request worked. just because `success` got triggered in JS is meaningless. that just means the http request came back with a 200 ok. you need to look at the json returned , e.g. `{"result":"not ok"}` or whatever.

Comment: OK, then how I should be getting the result returned and let's say display it on the current page?

Comment: try `console.log(data);` beside your `alert()`

Comment: Still going to the URL from the link and the movie starts playing, but when I checked the browser console, I'm getting this message::

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.0.102:8080/jsonrpc?request={%22jsonrpc%22:%222.0%22,%22id%22:%221%22,%22method%22:%22Player.Open%22,%22params%22:{%22item%22:{%22file%22:%22/media/serverhdd/cloud/Movies/Ex%20Machina/Ex%20Machina.mkv%22}}}. (Reason: CORS request failed).

Answer (score 0):

First solution suggested: You just need to use the event **preventDefault** jQuery function. The default in this situation is entering the link.

Alternative solution: Ok, this is not the first solution I've presented. But having in mind that the **right code** is not working, you can try this code that will fix it (or hack it).

```
$('.play_movie').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('hhref', href);
    $(this).attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
});

$('.play_movie').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var movie_url = $(this).attr('hhref');
    $.ajax({
        url: movie_url,
        success: function(data) {
            alert('done');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have alraedy tried this before posting the question here and this wasn't working..... Unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out... I've changed the design a bit... Instead of using a link, I thought it will be better to use a button and hard code the variables - the IP address and the movie destination. Of course I'll be able too get them from the database easily but this is just for testing purposes:

```
<button>Play movie</button>

<script>

    var KodiAddress = 'http://192.168.0.102:8080';

    $( 'button' ).click( function() {
        var kodioutput = $(this).attr('href');
        var URL = '/media/serverhdd/cloud/Movies/Ex Machina/Ex Machina.mkv';    // Grab Input Value
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: KodiAddress + '/jsonrpc',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            data: 'request=' + encodeURIComponent( '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Player.Open","params":{"item":{"file":"' + URL + '"}},"id":"1"}' )
        })
        .fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
            if ( jqXHR.status == 200 ) {
                alert('done');
            } else {
                alert('fail');
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Thank you all for looking into my problem!

Regards,
Ivan